# Adding two forecast objects in R

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I have two forecast objects, one obtained with ARIMA, where I forecast a deseasoned time series, and the other one that involves the seasonal component of the previous ts, forecasted with the seasonal naive method, so it repeats the last years. I'd like to combine those forecast in one object, by adding its values. How can I do it?

Here's the code

```
ts.comp <- stl(ts,  s.window="periodic")
deseasonal_ts <- seasadj(ts.comp)
fit <- auto.arima(deseasonal_ts, seasonal=FALSE)
prediction <- forecast(fit, h=30)

seasonal_ts <- ts.comp$time.series[,1]
seasonal_ts_prediction<- snaive(seasonal_ts, 30)
```

I'd like to combine `prediction` and `seasonal_ts_prediction`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in the following way:

```
predComb <- prediction$mean + seasonal_ts_prediction$mean
```

You can see the outcome:

```
foo <- ts.union(nottem, predComb) # for the nottem time-series 
plot(foo)
```

[image]